# ¿Cómo llamar a una función concreta de PHP desde Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Hola tengo la siguientes funciones ajax las cuales se dirigen al mismo archivo:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url.php",
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
          //Accion 1
}
});

$.ajax({
        url: "url.php",
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
         //Accion diferente al otro AJAX
}
});
```

**Archivo "url.php" donde llegan las funciones AJAX**

```
<?php



#CLASES
#**********************************************************************

class Ajax{

    #EJECUTA LA FUNCION 1
    #******************************************************************

    public function accion1(){

        //Se ejecuta lo que quiero en la funcion 1
   }

   #EJECUTA LA FUNCION 2
    #******************************************************************

    public function accion2(){

        //Se ejecuta lo que quiero en la funcion 2
   }
}

#OBJETOS
#************************************************************************

$a = new Ajax();
$a -> accion1();

$b = new Ajax();
$b -> accion2();

?>
```

Como puedo diferencia para que la primer funcion AJAX entre en la acción1 y la otra en la accion2?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hasta donde yo sé no se puede hacer referencia directamente a una función de PHP mediante AJAX. Sin embargo, lo que puedes hacer es pasar un parámetro a través del AJAX con el parámetro `data`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url.php",
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        data: {funcion: "funcion1"},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
          //Accion 1
}
});

$.ajax({
        url: "url.php",
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        data: {funcion: "funcion2"},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
         //Accion diferente al otro AJAX
}
});
```

Y desde el PHP comprobar dicho parámetro y ejecutar una función u otra en función del valor que nos llegue:

```
//Comprobamos que el valor no venga vacío
if(isset($_GET['funcion']) && !empty($_GET['funcion'])) {
    $funcion = $_GET['funcion'];

    //En función del parámetro que nos llegue ejecutamos una función u otra
    switch($funcion) {
        case 'funcion1': 
            $a -> accion1();
            break;
        case 'funcion2': 
            $b -> accion2();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, me sirvio , Muchas gracias